# How to get parameter when i click on buttonm in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> i have an issue, i need when i click on listItem, console.log it's "category" value but it return "undefined".

```
function Portfolio() {

    const handleClick  = (e)=>{
        console.log(e.target.category)

    }
    return (
        <Section>
            <Title><TitleSpan>My</TitleSpan> Portfolio</Title>
            <List>
                <ListItem active category={"all"} onClick={handleClick}>All</ListItem>
                <ListItem category={"html" }onClick={handleClick}>HTML</ListItem>
                <ListItem category={"photoshop"} onClick= 
                  {handleClick}>Photoshop</ListItem>
                <ListItem category={"wordpress"} onClick= 
                    {handleClick}>Wordpress</ListItem>
                <ListItem category={"mobile"} onClick={handleClick}>Mobile</ListItem>
            </List>
        </Section>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the event param, you can just pass the category this way too.

```
onClick={() => handleClick('mobile')}

const handleClick  = (category)=>{
  console.log(category)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because we don't have property `category`. You can use `name` instead.

```
const handleClick = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.name)
}

<ListItem active name="all" onClick={handleClick}>All</ListItem>
```

Comment: i tried to change category to name but still the issue founded

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 2nd argument.

```
<ListItem active category={"all"} onClick={(e)=>handleClick(e, 'all')}>All</ListItem>
```

After than you can collect value like this.

```
const handleClick  = (e, category)=>{
        console.log(category)

    }
```